# How to mod_rewrite on IIS webserver

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

As my previous server was a Linux powered machine I have this piece of code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NS,L]
</IfModule>
```

This piece of code will put the information in the URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/nr1/nr2/nr3/
```

into an array like this:

```
array ( 0 => "nr1", 1 => "nr2", 2 => "nr3")
```

My new server machine is an Windows 2008 (IIS) based server. Now i would like to use the mod_rewrite mod on my new server aswell. In short my question is:

Can anyone tell me, or link me to a tutorial that tells me, how to install/use the mod_rewrite mod (or any mod that does the same thing) and translate the code above into a format i can use on my windows based server.

**I still use php, not ASP.NET**, I know many people will say use apache or something, but IIS usage is needed unfortunately.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quite like the IIS Rewrite Module because it's fully integrated into the `web.config` file (the IIS equivalent of `.htaccess`).

But if you're after an exact syntax match, [ISAPI Rewrite is your friend](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/). It has (as far as I can tell anyway) 100% compatibility with Apache's `mod_rewrite` module in a `.htaccess` file (and actually uses a `.htaccess` file which looks *really* weird in Windows Explorer to see a valid file without a filename)

Comment: The only thing i care about is that i get the exact same output to my php (right now its a string of everyting behind the domain which i explode on `/` giving the array). If i can get this result from the rewrite module I'd be happy to use it. Any idea on how to translate this into the iis way of doing this? (I have not made this .htaccess code myself, and dont know much about it to be honest).

Comment: As the website may actually be migrated to a linux machine in the future i decided to use the Hellicon Ape (http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) mod. It seems to be exactly what i need!! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's Official IIS site has the [Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) you're looking for.

If you're familiar with mod_rewrite, the IIS equivalents are pretty similar. Otherwise there are plenty of guides around the net. The original intent of the module was to mirror mod_rewrite, so it's pretty similar though they have grown in slightly different directions.